# Asp.Net : Is it save to upload and files in web config folder?

Tags: asp.net

Is it good practice to store user's files(images,documents etc) in web config folder ? Is it gonna affect my website anyhow ?  Because i do know that it is unacceptable to store dynamic/user's files in the BIN folder. So now i'm trying to establish a folder path to store my dynamic files. The other reason is that my service provider said i'm only allowed to store files in the folder where i store my website because i'm hosting my website on a their shared server.

Comment: There is a potential security issue with this approach - if for some reason, somehow, a user posts not "an image" or "a document" but rather an executable file (*.asp, *.aspx, *.asmx, dozens of other extensions) then a moment later she could be able to invoke the request to that document and the server will happily execute it at its side.

Comment: Good point, so what's the best option ?

Comment: Have a separate folder, somewhere else, not under your application folder. Alternatively try to pick up one of non-navigable folders (App_Data, App_Code).

Comment: This is definitely the solution. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's safer to store uploaded files either:

- under the App_Data folder
- or, outside the website's root folder.

This ensures users can't navigate to the uploaded files.

In your case, your service provider's restrictions mean you should store them under App_Data.

Comment: I can't see this folder under my project. Do i have to create it manually(Right click + Add +  New folder) ? If not manually then what steps can i follow to create this folder ?

Comment: Found an option to add App_Data folder. The folder was created by VS automatically. Thanks Joe

Comment: Does this mean i have to store third party dlls in App_data as well? Currently i store them in one of the ordinary folder(.cs files folder), and then add them as a reference from that ordinary folder.

Comment: Why do you need to store the 3rd party DLLs? The only place they will be loaded is if they are in the Bin folder - you don't need them anywhere else when you deploy.

Comment: I didn't know. At least i have learned something new today. Thank you for your guide Dan.

Answer (score 0):

A 'web config folder' doesn't really exist. The web.config is a file that can exist at any level in your website directory structure.

To answer your question: simply create a folder anywhere under your website and store the files there. You can create different directories for each user if necessary. This should not adversely affect your website in any way. But... if you expect hundreds of  thousands of files, you may need another solution.